# how to loop through a folder of csv files and read header of each? then output in a folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm a newbie in python and need help with this piece of code. I did a lot of search to get to this stage but couldn't fix it on my own. Thanks in advance for your help.

What I'm trying to do is that I have to compare 100+ csv files in a folder, and not all have the same number of columns or columns name. So I'm trying to use python to read the headers of each file and put in a csv file to output in a folder.

I got to this point but not sure if I'm on the right path even:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\user1\Downloads\2016GAdata' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

list1 = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    list1.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list1, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(frame)
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this not working for you? If they have different columns then you wont be able to concatenate them.

Comment: why not use `reader = csv.DictReader(filename)` and `column_names = reader.fieldnames`?

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish  can you please add them in code? I couldn't understand what you mean. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary whose key is filename and value is dataframe columns. Using this dictionary to create dataframe results in filename as index and column names as column value.

```py
d = {}

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    d[filename] = df.columns

frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

```
           0     1     2       3
file1  Fruit  Date  Name  Number
file2  Fruit  Date  Name    None
```

Comment: hmm makes sense to me as newbie but how can I write the results in a csv so that I view the results in a better way?  print(frame) was not helpful for me.

Comment: @SobenDevUR Use `frame.to_csv(file_path)`.